# Why do you need to change drives in cmd prompts?

Tags: windows, cmd, cd

In a cmd prompt, if you want to go from

```
c:\foo\
```

to

```
d:\bar\
```

You must type

```
d:
```

to change drive first, before you can

```
cd d:\bar\
```

On Linux, you do not have to do this. Why does cmd unintuitively make you have to do this? Historical? Implementation limitation? By design?

I understand that

```
cd /d
```

mimics the Linux behavior, however why is Linux's behavior not default? 
As far as I can tell when you

```
cd anotherDrive:\directory\
```

it just does nothing, so it's not like the "without /D" usage is reserved for some other semantics.

Comment: Actually, `cd v:\whatever` doesn't do nothing. It changes the working directory on the other drive. The reason for this behavior is to maintain backward compatibility (this goes all the way back to DOS 2.0).

Answer (score 4):

Having one current working directory per drive allows you to do things like

```
> cd d:\some\long\path\     # Set the working directory of that other drive
> copy myFile.txt d:        # Copy the current file to that drive
> cd ..                     # Go elsewhere
> copy anotherFile.txt d:   # Copy another
```

I bet this was handy back in the days when you worked with 2 floppy drives.

I don't see any technical reasons for this. Presumably just a design choice of how to work with the prompt.

As PA. mentions you can use the [`/d`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490875.aspx) switch if you don't like this behaviour.

Comment: definitive useful - I use this quite often.

Comment: This is the answer. On Windows every drive letter has it's own current directory, so `cd anotherDrive:\directory\` actually does something. The current drive is a separate thing, so it's possible to change the current drive with out changing the current directory on any of the drives or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to

just read `HELP CD`

and then try

```
    CD /d d:\bar
```

the `CD` default behavior is still there for backwards compatibility with old versions of DOS where the existence of dual diskette bays made it useful.

Newer commands, like `pushd` for example, make the default behavior to honor drive and path.